# Fetching selected attribute in entities

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, nsfetchrequest

I have a core-data entity with several attributes, and I want a list of all the objects in one attribute. My code looks like this:

```
        let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
        let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!

        let sortDesc = NSSortDescriptor(key: "username", ascending: true)

        let fetchReq = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Identities")
        fetchReq.sortDescriptors = [sortDesc]
        fetchReq.valueForKey("username")

        let en = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Identities", inManagedObjectContext: context)

        userList = context.executeFetchRequest(fetchReq, error: nil) as [Usernames]
```

But this gives me an NSException-error, and I can't figure out why, or how I'm supposed to do this. I've read the NSFetchRequest class description but couldn't make much sense out of it.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

EDIT: After a tip from Bluehound I changed my code to this:

```
var userList = [Model]()
@IBAction func printUsers(sender: AnyObject) {
    let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!

    let sortDesc = NSSortDescriptor(key: "friendID", ascending: true)

    let fetchReq = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Identities")
    fetchReq.sortDescriptors = [sortDesc]
    fetchReq.propertiesToFetch = ["friendID"]

    let en = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Identities", inManagedObjectContext: context)

    userList = context.executeFetchRequest(fetchReq, error: nil) as [Model]

    println(userList)

}
```

The runtime error is gone but I still don't know if it works because I'm not sure how to convert the list to a list of strings.

As always, suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Use `NSFetchRequest`'s `propertiesToFetch` property instead of `valueForKey`

Comment: @Bluehound Can you please show me, I'm having trouble initializing the NSPropertyDescription.

Comment: What does the output of println(userList) look like?

Comment: @pbasdf [ , , ] the same as when I've fetched the whole class.

Comment: OK.  Try adding  `fetchReq.resultType = .DictionaryResultType`.

Comment: @pbasdf That gives me an error in the println-function saying the NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type.

Comment: Oh, sorry, and change `as [Model]` to `as [AnyObject]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two possibilities: You can issue a normal fetch request 
and extract an array containing the wanted attribute from the result,
using `map()`:

```
let fetchReq = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Identities")
fetchReq.sortDescriptors = [sortDesc]

var error : NSError?
if let result = context.executeFetchRequest(fetchReq, error: &error) as? [Model] {
    let friendIDs = map(result) { $0.friendID }
    println(friendIDs)
} else {
    println("fetch failed: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
}
```

**Swift 2:**

```
let fetchReq = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Identities")
fetchReq.sortDescriptors = [sortDesc]

do {
    let result = try context.executeFetchRequest(fetchReq) as! [Model]
    let friendIDs = result.map { $0.friendID }
    print(friendIDs)
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("fetch failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Or you set the `resultType` to  `.DictionaryResultType`
and `propertiesToFetch` to the wanted attribute.
In this case the fetch request will return an array of dictionaries:

```
let fetchReq = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Identities")
fetchReq.sortDescriptors = [sortDesc]
fetchReq.propertiesToFetch = ["friendID"]
fetchReq.resultType = .DictionaryResultType

var error : NSError?
if let result = context.executeFetchRequest(fetchReq, error: &error) as? [NSDictionary] {
    let friendIDs = map(result) { $0["friendID"] as String }
    println(friendIDs)
} else {
    println("fetch failed: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
}
```

**Swift 2:**

```
let fetchReq = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Identities")
fetchReq.sortDescriptors = [sortDesc]
fetchReq.propertiesToFetch = ["friendID"]
fetchReq.resultType = .DictionaryResultType

do {
    let result = try context.executeFetchRequest(fetchReq) as! [NSDictionary]
    let friendIDs = result.map { $0["friendID"] as! String }
    print(friendIDs)
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("fetch failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

The second method has the advantage that only the specified properties
are fetched from the database, not the entire managed objects.

It has the disadvantage that the result does not include pending
unsaved changes in the managed object context (`includesPendingChanges:`
is implicitly set to `false` when using `.DictionaryResultType`).

Comment: I have taken the entity name "Identities" and the name of the managed object subclass "Model" from the code in your question. Normally one would use the same name for both.

Comment: Thank you once again Martin, you never disappoint :) Yes, I know the names are not optimal, it's just a "test-project" I created a long time ago.