# Delete object in core data, failed to match the Swift Array Element type

Tags: ios, arrays, uitableview, swift, core-data

When I'm trying to delete objects from my core data I get this error:

```
fatal error: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type
```

and I have to idea why this happens. My table view is divided into sections, maybe that has something to do with it? I have never had any problem with deleting core-data from a table view before, so this is very strange to me.

My code looks like this:

```
var userList = [User]()
var usernames = [String]()

        viewDidLoad(){
        let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
        let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!

        let fetchReq = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "User")
        let en = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("User", inManagedObjectContext: context)
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "username", ascending: true)
        fetchReq.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
        fetchReq.propertiesToFetch = ["username"]
        fetchReq.resultType = .DictionaryResultType

        userList = context.executeFetchRequest(fetchReq, error: nil) as [User]
}


        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

            let editedCell = self.tv.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)

            let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
            let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!

            if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {

                if let tv = tableView as Optional{

                    let textLbl = editedCell?.textLabel?.text
                    let ind = find(usernames, textLbl!)! as Int

                    context.deleteObject(userList[ind] as NSManagedObject)

                    userList.removeAtIndex(ind)

                    tv.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
                }
          } 
    }
```

In my code, the `usernames` array is just an array with all the usernames retrieved from core data in `userList`.

The errors appears last in my code where I'm trying to delete the object from the `context`, and from the `userList`; it's the same error in both lines. I've tried casting my `userList` as `Array<AnyObject>` but then I also got an runtime error with zero clues to what was wrong.

Any suggestions on how to solve this issue would be very appreciated.

Comment: Is User an NSManagedObject subclass?  If so you shouldn't need "as NSManagedObject" in your delete - the fact that you have it makes me suspect that your subclass isn't registered and you are getting plain NSManagedObjects, not User objects which is why you are getting the array type error.  Try setting userList as [NSManagedObject] rather than [User]

Comment: @Paulw11 I now declare the userList as userList:[NSManagedObject] and retrieve it "as [NSManagedObject]", I also tried removing the "as NSManagedObject" in my delete. It's still not working, and yes, User is a subclass of NSManagedObject.

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint and examine the array?

Comment: @Paulw11 I could, but I'm really not sure what I would be looking for.

Comment: What type is in the array? Swift is complaining that it isn't what you said it was going to be

Comment: @Paulw11 Well, I'm a little lost with the breakpoints, so I can't figure out what type is in the array, but when I define the type as 'string' in my data model, shouldn't the only options be strings or NSManagedObjects?

Comment: @Paulw11 I also tried removing the two lines where I deleted the objects from core-data, but I still got this error: 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

Comment: Yes, you can't process the delete without updating the data source because `numberOfRowsInSection` will be wrong

Comment: @Paulw11 Oh yes, rookie mistake, sorry about that. But I still can't see what the error is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With

```
fetchReq.resultType = .DictionaryResultType
```

the fetch request

```
userList = context.executeFetchRequest(fetchReq, error: nil) as [User]
```

returns an array of `NSDictionary` objects, not an array of `User` objects, and you are just deluding the compiler with the cast
`as [User]`.

For performance reasons, the Swift runtime does not verify at this point
if all array elements are really `User` objects, so this assignment
succeeds. But as soon as you *access* an array element, for example with

```
userList[ind]
```

then you get the runtime exception because the element type (`NSDictionary`)  does not match the array type (`User`).

Also you *cannot* cast a dictionary back to the managed object,
so this will never work:

```
context.deleteObject(userList[ind] as NSManagedObject)
```

The best solution is probably just to *remove* the lines

```
fetchReq.propertiesToFetch = ["username"]
fetchReq.resultType = .DictionaryResultType
```

so that the fetch request returns an array of `User` objects, and
adjust the rest of your code if necessary.

You might have a look again at the two different solutions proposed
in https://stackoverflow.com/a/28055573/1187415.
The first one returns an array of managed objects, and the second one
an array of dictionaries. What you have done here is to *mix* the
solutions by setting the result type to `.DictionaryResultType`,
but treating the result as an array of managed objects.

*Remark:* I would recommend to use a [`NSFetchedResultsController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/)
to display the results of a Core Data fetch request in a table view.
The FRC efficiently manages the table view data source (with optional
grouping into sections), and *updates* the table view automatically
if the result set changes.