# Getting both attribute name and value when reading from core data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, dictionary

I need to get both the attribute name and the value for the attribute when I'm reading from my core data, is there any easy way of doing this?

I've been trying to retrieve the first element in my object model as a Dictionary, but that gives me an error saying:

> fatal error: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element
>   type

My code looks like this:

```
    let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!

    let fetchReq = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "ActiveIndexes")
    fetchReq.resultType = NSFetchRequestResultType.DictionaryResultType

    receivedList = context.executeFetchRequest(fetchReq, error: nil) as! [ActiveIndexes]

    println(receivedList[0])
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28131227/delete-object-in-core-data-failed-to-match-the-swift-array-element-type to me ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSManagedObject`s have a rich API for introspection.

```
let activeIndex = retrievedList[0]
for (key, value) in activeIndex.entity.attributesByName {
    println("\(key) : \(activeIndex.valueForKey(key as NSString))")
}
```