# Swift - Core Data return all rows for attribute

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, core-data

I'd like to return all rows for a given attribute stored in my core data entity. I know how to retrieve rows based on a filtered predicate, but I would like to be able to return all of the rows without specifying a value for the predicate. The code I'm currently using is as follows:

```
func getUsername() -> NSString {
        var appDel: AppDelegate =      (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate)
    var context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!

    var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "User")
    //request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    //request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "fstrUsername = %@", pstrUsername)

    var results:NSArray = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)!

    if results.count > 0 {
        var res = results[0] as NSManagedObject
        return res.valueForKey("fstrUsername") as NSString
    }
    else {
        return "false"
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to return all rows for an attribute without having to specify a full or partial value to match on in the predicate? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for [Fetching selected attribute in entities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28054621/fetching-selected-attribute-in-entities) ? – Btw, if you just don't set a predicate then all objects of the given entity are fetched.

Comment: If you don't want a predicate, don't use one, that's literally all there is to it. With no predicate you get all instances of the entity. What problem(s) are you having with this?

Comment: Thanks for the help, guys. I removed the predicate and it's working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the predicate code and you will retrieve all the rows!