# Swift Get an Array of dates from ManagedObjectContext FetchRequest

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, core-data, nspredicate

I am trying to make an array of NSDates for a Date attribute in Core Data (an array of save dates). So I can show on a calendar where there are days with items saved. I have tried with the code below but get an error:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "savedTime"

```
func datesWithSavedData() -> [NSDate] {
  let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "UserData")
  fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "savedTime'")
  fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "savedTime", ascending: false)]
  do {
    let results =
      try managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as? [NSDate]
    selectedDates = results!
    print(selectedDates)
  } catch let error as NSError {
    print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
  }

  return selectedDates as! [NSDate]
}
```

Comment: `NSPredicate(format: "savedTime'")` makes no sense. Predicates are for *filtering* the result set, so what do you want to achieve? If you want all entries then omit the predicate.

Comment: I have tried that and get error of "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" on the line  selectedDates = results!

Comment: Date and I saved them as nsdate.

Comment: `executeFetchRequest` returns always `[NSManagedObject]` by default. But you can get an array of simple dictionaries by setting the `resultType` of the request to `.DictionaryResultType` and `propertiesToFetch` to an array of the desired properties. Then you could use the `map` function or KVC to get your `NSDate` array.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28054621/fetching-selected-attribute-in-entities (now updated for Swift 2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution is to tell Core Data to return a dictionary array rather than `[NSManagedObject]` for example

```
func datesWithSavedData() -> [NSDate] {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "UserData")
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "savedTime", ascending: false)]
    fetchRequest.resultType = .DictionaryResultType
    fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = ["savedTime"]
    do {
       let results = try managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [[String:NSDate]]
       return results.map { $0["savedTime"] as! NSDate }

    } catch let error as NSError {
       print(error)
       return [NSDate]()
    }
}
```

**Swift 3+**

```
func datesWithSavedData() -> [Date] {
    let fetchRequest : NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "UserData")
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "savedTime", ascending: false)]
    fetchRequest.resultType = .dictionaryResultType
    fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = ["savedTime"]
    do {
       let results = try managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [[String:Date]]
       return results.map { $0["savedTime"] as! Date }

    } catch {
       print(error)
       return [Date]()
    }
}
```

Comment: This works and gives a dictionary of nsdates perfect! The other solution gives an output of the whole entity from core data not just the date.